# Ssis convert variable of type string to Int32

Tags: ssis

I have a variable "RowCountStr" in my ssis package of type string, I have another variable "RowCountInt" of type Int32, I need to compare these two variables. I tried to type cast the variable "RowCountStr" but I could not, please let me know how can I typecast a variable of type string to Int32.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you try to cast it? Can you please share your code? Also, where are you doing this? In a constraint, a `Script Task` or somewhere else?

Comment: I did not use Script Task, I used (DT_STR, 30, 1252) @[User::RowCountStr], I think this is typecasting from WSTR to STR, but I do not find any datatype is ssis to hold STR. I have 2 different RowCounts one from RowCount transformation (Int32) and another from my flatfile header & I wanted to compare these both.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to cast an integer as a string, try this:

```
(DT_STR,10,1252)@[User::IntegerVariable]
```

To cast from string to integer, try this;

```
(DT_I4)@[User::StringVariable]
```

You may also want to check for `NULL` values in the string variable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no null value. I can typecast from DT_WSTR to DT_STR using the first typecast that you mentioned, and I want to store this in a new user variable. What datatype should I use for this new user variable, please advise.

Comment: That should be a String variable since thats what the casting does.